# jQuery - Naming convention, selector or element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, element

This may be the dumbest question ever asked but i can't find a definitive answer and it is driving me insane.

**Are ALL selectors passed to the jQuery constructor considered an element ?**

DOM elements such as HTML, HEAD, BODY, DIV, SECTION, A, P ect. are all elements of the Document Object Model.

What about selectors such as window and document are they also elements?

I ask this silly question because when it comes to naming convention i often see jQuery selectors refered to as elements or passed as function arguments using as *el*, *element* or even *elem*.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're wrapping it like `$(window)` you'll have the window object, but `$('window')` will attempt to select all the `<window></window>`  elements in the DOM

Comment: ok, so when referring to elements in a broad sense, say and a set of selectors returning a variety of HTML elements, a selector returning the window object will not be considered part of the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *element* is a node in the DOM, or the Javascript object that represents a node.

A *selector* is a string that's used to specify which elements to find in the DOM. jQuery selectors are similar to CSS selectors. Selectors include tag names like `div`, ID selectors like `#container`, class selectors like `.myclass`, attribute selectors like `[name=username]`, pseudo-selectors like `:checked`, and lots of combinations of these.

The `jQuery()` function can accept either an element or a selector as an argument, and will return a jQuery collection object that contains the specified elements. If you give it an element, it simply wraps it in a jQuery object; if you give it a selector, it searches the DOM for the matching elements, and wraps them in a jQuery object.

In the code below, `jquery` and `jquery2` are effectively equivalent:

```
var element = document.getElementById("someid");
var jquery1 = $(element);

var selector = "#someid";
var jquery2 = $(selector);
```

The `jQuery()` function can also accept other kinds of input that aren't directly relevant to your question.

Comment: That makes sense, so in this context an element is value returned by the selector? Where does that leave the window/document, when returned by a selector are these also considered to be an "element"? Just to be clear i am thinking in a rather broad sense of the term as i realize everything that is wrapped in jQuery() is technically a object.

Comment: When you call `jQuery()`, it returns a jQuery collection object, and this contains DOM element objects.